# Jquery getJSON from url and hide URL in source

Tags: jquery, json

I'm making a call to a JSON webservice using jQuery which works fine, aside from the URL I'm calling needs to be hidden in the source. I'm trying to use a local page as the url parameter for $.getJSON, this page will then redirect to the JSON service. If I call the page in a browser it correctly redirects and displays the JSON data, but  $.getJSON is not picking it up.

```
$.getJSON("Customer.html", function (result) {
```

Customer.html redirects in the following way to call JSON.

```
<script>
       window.location = "http://MYJSONURL";
</script>
```

Any other idea's or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: That's fundamentally impossible.  Anyone can see every URL involved in the developer tools.

Comment: Use server-side code.

Comment: I was trying to avoid server-side. I've tried making it a session variable or array object in a session variable as well but that shows up in the source as well.

Comment: are you confusing session with cookie? session's do create a session cookie, but the session cookie usually just contains a session id, the actual values stay on the server (unless you output them, of course)

Comment: Even if you hid it in the source, I can see the exact URL my browser is requesting by using its dev tools!

Comment: The browser *has* to know where the URL is or how will it load? And if the browser knows, the user can find it (which as mentioned a billion times already, dev tools available to most browsers will easily be able to capture that URL).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trouble is the `$.getJSON` call is expecting to get back some JSON (which is just some text). Your **Customer.html** file is sending back a small piece of JavaScript which when run *in a browser* redirects the browser to wherever you want.

When `getJSON` tries to interpret **Customer.html** as JSON it will fail as it just doesn't have the capability to work out it has just received some html, let alone work out how a browser would behave if it received it.

Have you tried sending a redirect header from Customer.html?

But if the page is not being server from a web server you can't do that. 
So instead try this:

Change Customer.html to this:

```
{ 
  "url": "http://MYJSONURL"
}
```

then change your code to this 2-stage process which reads the URL from the Customer page and then gets the final piece of JSON from there:

```
$.getJSON("Customer.html", function (urldata) {
   var url = urldata.url;
   $.getJSON(url, function (result) {

   <your present code here>

}
```

Of course, it would be good idea to change the name of Customer.html to Customer.json.

Comment: This appears to work, but on a side note I settled for the simpler solution of just putting my function in a .js file. I figured both this way and my way are about the same, meaning the url is still obtainable but not visible in the page source. Thanks for the reply Annabel.

Comment: Of course the URL *will* be visible in your JavaScript file, which is also a source page. In most browsers like Chrome you go **View Source** then links to the script files will appear as hyperlinks which you click to view the JavaScript.  Whatever method you use to try and hide the URL it will be accessible to a web savvy individual who could read your JavaScript to see how the URL is obtained. Or they could use a tool like **Fiddler2** which displays each URL requested by the browser however hidden they are.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you can call to web services directly like this

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "RSSReader.asmx/GetRSSReader",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
           var items = [];
           $.each(data, function(key, val) {
             items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');
           });

         $('<ul/>', {
            'class': 'my-new-list',
            html: items.join('')
          }).appendTo('body');
        }
      });
    });
```

Comment: Yes, while something like this works, just like $.getJSON("serviceurl", function (result){}); works also, but both options would expose the URL.